# How to set the environment variable in cloudbuild.yaml file?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, yaml, google-cloud-build

I am trying to set GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS. Is this correct way to set environment variable ? Below is my yaml file:

```
steps:
- name: 'node:10.10.0'
  id: installing_npm
  args: ['npm', 'install']
  dir: 'API/system_performance'
- name: 'node:10.10.0'
  #entrypoint: bash
  args: ['bash', 'set GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=test/emc-ema-cp-d-267406-a2af305d16e2.json']
  id: run_test_coverage
  args: ['npm', 'run', 'coverage']
  dir: 'API/system_performance'
```

Please help me solve this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [`env` step parameter](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/build-config#env)

However, when you execute Cloud Build, [the platform uses its own service account](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/securing-builds/set-service-account-permissions#what_is_the_service_account) (in the future, it will be possible to specify the service account that you want to use)

Thus, if you grant the Cloud Build service account with the correct role, you don't need to use a key file (which is committed in your Git repository, not a really good practice!)

Comment: Hi @guillaume-blaquiere would you know if by chance is now possible to do it "in the future, it will be possible to specify the service account that you want to use"? I've been exhaustively trying without success. Tks

Comment: Cloud Build now support user managed service account: https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/securing-builds/configure-user-specified-service-accounts if you have issues, open a question, I will be happy to help

Comment: Hi @guillaume-blaquiere, appreciate you help. Just posted a question here  Tkd

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76071225/deploy-dataflow-pipeline-via-cloud-build-using-specific-sa