# Deploy Dataflow pipeline via Cloud Build using specific SA

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, continuous-deployment, google-cloud-build, google-cloud-iam

I'm exhaustively trying to deploy a Dataflow pipeline from Cloud Build with a specific SA (rather than the default Cloud Build SA) and so far without success.

I followed this process - https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/securing-builds/configure-user-specified-service-accounts

The key has the following roles granted (there’re more than the Doc recommended)

- Dataflow Admin
- Dataflow Worker
- Logs Writer
- Service Account User
- Storage Admin
- Storage Object Admin

Command line deploy

```py
os.system("python3.7 /workspace/runner.py \
    --runner=DataflowRunner \
    --job_name=test \
    --project=XXXXXX \
    --temp_location=gs://staging/tmp \
    --region=europe-west1 \
    --environment=dev \
    --max_num_workers=20 \
    --autoscaling_algorithm=THROUGHPUT_BASED \
    --setup_file=/workspace/setup.py \
    --service_account_email=XXXX@XXXX.iam.gserviceaccount.com \
    ")
```

Error:

```
apitools.base.py.exceptions.HttpForbiddenError: HttpError accessing <https://dataflow.googleapis.com/v1b3/projects/my-prj/locations/europe-west1/jobs?alt=json>: response: <{'vary': 'Origin, X-Origin, Referer', 'content-type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8', 'date': 'Tue, 18 Apr 2023 14:03:30 GMT', 'server': 'ESF', 'cache-control': 'private', 'x-xss-protection': '0', 'x-frame-options': 'SAMEORIGIN', 'x-content-type-options': 'nosniff', 'transfer-encoding': 'chunked', 'status': '403', 'content-length': '812', '-content-encoding': 'gzip'}>, content <{
  "error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "(3b12042024f17c98): Current user cannot act as service account XXXXXXX@XXXXXX.iam.gserviceaccount.com. Please grant your user account one of [Owner, Editor, Service Account Actor] roles, or any other role that includes the iam.serviceAccounts.actAs permission. See https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/service-accounts-actas for additional details. Causes: (3b12042024f17239): Current user cannot act as service account XXXX@XXXX.iam.gserviceaccount.com. Please grant your user account one of [Owner, Editor, Service Account Actor] roles, or any other role that includes the iam.serviceAccounts.actAs permission. See https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/service-accounts-actas for additional details.",
    "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED"
  }
}
```

That's the output message from Dataflow when I click the link `HttpError accessing <https://dataflow.googleapis.com/v1b3/projects/my-prj/locations/europe-west1/jobs?alt=json>`

```json
{
  "error": {
    "code": 401,
    "message": "Request is missing required authentication credential. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.",
    "status": "UNAUTHENTICATED",
    "details": [
      {
        "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ErrorInfo",
        "reason": "CREDENTIALS_MISSING",
        "domain": "googleapis.com",
        "metadata": {
          "service": "dataflow.googleapis.com",
          "method": "google.dataflow.v1beta3.JobsV1Beta3.ListJobs"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Please share the command line you used to deploy your Dataflow pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

By default if you not set a service account in the command line that launches the `Dataflow` job, the default `Compute` service account is used.

In the command line that launches the `Dataflow` job, you can set a [user specified Service Account](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/concepts/security-and-permissions) :

Example with Java and Maven :

```bash
mvn compile exec:java \
  -Dexec.mainClass=com.package.MainClass \
  -Dexec.args=" \
  --project=project \
  --runner=DataflowRunner \
  --serviceAccount=your-sa-email
  "
  ....
```

Example with Python :

```bash
python -m folder.main \
    --project=project \
    --runner=DataflowRunner \
    --region=europe-west1 \
    --setup_file=./setup.py \
    --temp_location=gs://mazlum_dev/dataflow/temp \
    --service_account_email=your-sa-email
  ....
```

This user specified Service Account needs to have the expected roles to launch the job and also a role allowing to act as :

- Dataflow developer
- Dataflow worker
- Service Account Token Creator

Comment: Just added this other question after realising it can potentially not related to Cloud Build, but with the fact of using a SA from a different project where at the Job is being deployed - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76085687/denied-to-deploy-dataflow-job-under-prj-a-using-sa-from-prj-b