# Denied to deploy Dataflow Job under "prj_A" using SA from "prj_B"

Tags: google-cloud-platform, deployment, google-cloud-dataflow, permission-denied, google-cloud-iam

I've recently posted [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76071225/deploy-dataflow-pipeline-via-cloud-build-using-specific-sa/76071442#76071442) but after several tries, and decoupling Cloud Build service I realised the `PERMISSION_DENIED` has nothing related to Cloud Build, but instead, with the fact of trying to deploy a Dafaflow Job in `prj_A` passing as PipelineOptions `service_account_email` a Service Account created under `prj_B`

This **WORKS** (args `project` and `service_account_email` under the same project, `prj_A`)

```py
options = PipelineOptions(
    runner='DataflowRunner',
    job_name='dataflow_job',
    project='prj_A',
    region='europe-west1',
    service_account_email='my-sa@prj_A.iam.gserviceaccount.com',
    temp_location='gs://bucket/tmp/'
)
```

This returns **`PERMISSION_DENIED`** (arg `project` under `prj_A` and `service_account_email` under `prj_B`)

```py
options = PipelineOptions(
    runner='DataflowRunner',
    job_name='dataflow_job',
    project='prj_A',
    region='europe-west1',
    service_account_email='my-sa@prj_B.iam.gserviceaccount.com',
    temp_location='gs://bucket/tmp/'
)
```

Access Granted under `prj_a` to `my-sa@prj_A.iam.gserviceaccount.com` – and working.

```
- Dataflow Admin
- Dataflow Worker
- Service Account User
- Storage Admin
- Storage Object Admin
```

Access Granted under `prj_a` to `my-sa@prj_B.iam.gserviceaccount.com` – and NOT working.

```
- Dataflow Admin
- Dataflow Developer
- Dataflow Worker
- Service Account Token Creator
- Service Account User
- Storage Admin
- Storage Object Admin
```

Additionally granted under `prj_b` to `my-sa@prj_B.iam.gserviceaccount.com` as described in Google Dataflow Doc [here](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/concepts/security-and-permissions#specify_a_user-managed_worker_service_account) the following roles/services (see screenshot added)

```
- Service Account Token Creator role (iam.serviceAccountTokenCreator)
- Service Account User role (iam.serviceAccountUser
```

For

- `Dataflow Service Account` (service-**prj_A**@dataflow-service-producer-prod.iam.gserviceaccount.com)
- `Compute Engine Service Agent` (service-**prj_A**@compute-system.iam.gserviceaccount.com) Google-managed service accounts on the user-managed service account.

[image]

Given all the tries so far, the only assumption I've that could explain is the fact of `prj_A` and `prj_B` are not residing under the same organisation, however I haven't found anything stating it for Dataflow Job, only for Cloud Build in [Limitations](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/securing-builds/configure-user-specified-service-accounts#cross-project_set_up) or Cross Projects

`PERMISSION_DENIED` full description

```
    "message": "(8d69bea36f304589): Current user cannot act as service account my-sa@prj_B.iam.gserviceaccount.com. Please grant your user account one of [Owner, Editor, Service Account Actor] roles, or any other role that includes the iam.serviceAccounts.actAs permission. See https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/service-accounts-actas for additional details. Causes: (8d69bea36f304874): Current user cannot act as service account my-sa@prj_B.iam.gserviceaccount.com. Please grant your user account one of [Owner, Editor, Service Account Actor] roles, or any other role that includes the iam.serviceAccounts.actAs permission. See https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/service-accounts-actas for additional details.",
    "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED"
  }
```

Comment: I proposed you an answer, I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

When you deploy a job under dataflow, a service agent perform the operation for you (something like a bot that perform the packaging and the deployment of your code on the Dataflow service).

The pattern of this service agent service account is `service-<projectNumber>@dataflow-service-producer-prod.iam.gserviceaccount.com`

---

When you deploy your pipeline, the service agent must act as the service account B to generate the tokens and all the credential material (to set in the metadata server).

That's why, you have to grant the `service-<projectNumber A>@dataflow-service-producer-prod.iam.gserviceaccount.com` on to the service account B (in the project B, or directly at the project level) the role `roles/iam.serviceAccountUser`

Like that, the service agent will be able to use the service account B in your project, and run the pipeline with it.

*Note: you don't need to grant that permission when you use a service account in the project A because the service agent is automatically granted on all the service account in the same project*

Comment: Hey guillaume-blaquiere, is it not what I exactly mention in "(...) Additionally granted to (...)? I know sometimes it sounds confusing...

Comment: No. You have to grant the project A dataflow service agent on your Service Account in the Project B as Service Account User. Service Account project B is set for the Dataflow runtime. You have to set the permission  on the service agent to create the pipeline (with the service account project B)

Comment: "You have to grant the **project A dataflow service agent** on your **Service Account in the Project B** as **Service Account User**"
My SA - `my-sa@prj_B.iam.gserviceaccount.com`
Granted under **prj_B** the follow of **prj_A**
- Dataflow Service Account (`service-prj_A@dataflow-service-producer-prod.iam.gserviceaccount.com`)
- Compute Engine Service Agent (`service-prj_A@compute-system.iam.gserviceaccount.com`). I also added a prepared screenshot of the process in the console into the question. Also, please notice I mentioned the projects are **not** under the `No Organisation`

Comment: * projects are not under the any organisation - No Organisation

Comment: Organization doesn't matter here. And despite all your grants, it still not work? If not, I can't help you more, you followed the exact documentation! https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/concepts/security-and-permissions#specify_a_user-managed_worker_service_account

Comment: I really appreciate your help Guillaume, but unfortunately not. If ‘No Organisation’ projects is not a limitation (as it is for Cloud Build)[https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/securing-builds/configure-user-specified-service-accounts#cross-project_set_up] I have no explanation for it.

Answer (score 0):

To solve this issue :

- Run the `Dataflow` job in the **project B**
- The service account is created for example in the **project B**
- In the `IAM` menu of projet A, give the needed permissions for the **project B SA** to access to the services in the **projet A**
- In the `IAM` menu of projet B, give the permissions for the **project B SA** to launch a `Dataflow` job in the **project B**
- When you launch your `Dataflow` job in the **project B**, set a program argument indicating what [Service Account email](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/concepts/security-and-permissions#python) launches the job :

For `Dataflow` `Python` :

```
--service_account_email=my-service-account-name@<project-id>.iam.gserviceaccount.com
```

Comment: Mazlum, appreciate your attempt, but this and other actions were done as per clearly detailed on the post. Please notice the python code and the arg service_account_email.

Comment: You're welcome Rubens. I had this issue previously and I think the orientation I given is a good way to solve it. If you can create the SA in the project that launches the job and gives the needed permissions in the 2 projects, it should work.

Comment: It does solve the issue in fact Mazlum, and that’s what I ended up doing – args ‘project’ and ‘service_account_email’ key under the **same project**. However, Google doesn’t state this requirement anywhere.

Comment: Yes you are right, it would have been better to have the info in the doc. I think to write an article on it. Can you mark the answer as solved please with an upvote to make the answer more valuable ?

Comment: I’m sorry Mazlum but the answer was already given in the question. 
“This WORKS (args project and service_account_email under the same project, prj_A)”. You could instead upvote the question, this would make much more sense. Thank you for your help anyways.